# create click function in jquery for all anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, anchor

I want to create a function that as long the user clicks on any anchor, a popup message shows.

So what I did is to call the anchor tag using jquery:

```
$('a').click(function(){
alert("yeah");
});
```

But it seems its not calling the said click function.I have other click functions before and after it and they all seem to be working fine except this. What should I do to get all the anchor clicks?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a syntax error somewhere else? That code is working.  Try it out yourself:  
On a PC type CMD+SHIFT+J or on a mac type CMD+OPT+J while using chrome to bring up the console.  Copy paste your function and press enter.  Then click on any link on this page, and an alert will pop up.

Comment: I've noticed that I have not placed it in a $(document).ready() function, would that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: yes. that would do it

Comment: whenever you bind a listener to an object using jQuery, it has to be after all of the DOM is rendered so that the listener has access to the right elements to listen to.